# Starting a thread multiple times doesn't cause a java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException on some devices

Tags: java, android

```
public class Test {

  private static class MyThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyThread myThread = new MyThread();

    myThread.start();

    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    myThread.start();
  }

}
```

This code is invalid, because the API of Thread.start() says

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.
>
> Throws:
>   IllegalThreadStateException - if the thread was already started.

And running it on my Windows machine causes a java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException.

Putting the same exact code from the main in an Android App gives me no exception on a Samsung S4 with LineageOS, a Wileyfox Swift 2X, BQ Aquaris X, Samsung Galaxy S5 Mini and a Sony Xperia M with LineageOS.
But the Google Play Developer Console shows a crash on a Samsung Galaxy S8. Also the emulator shows the exception.

Why does it work on some devices if the API documentation is so clear?

Edit: Added the code used in Android as requested via comments.

```
private static class MyThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
}

private void testThread() {
    MyThread myThread = new MyThread();

    myThread.start();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    myThread.start();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void takePicture() {
    lockFocus();

    testThread();
    Log.d("foobar", "test thread");
}
```

Comment: This has crashed on every version of ANdroid I've ever seen it run on.  I highly doubt there's actually one where it doesn't.  Since the above isn't even legal Android code, I don't know what you expect to happen  (to start with-  Android doesn't use main())

Comment: You're right, it's not the "exact" same code. Instead of running it in the main, I was running it from an onClick event.

Comment: Are you sure your click handler was properly hooked up and getting called?  Because that will crash every version of Android.

Comment: I edited the question and added the Android code for you. No Exception on the listed devices, but in the emulator.